# In which table access_token stored when we use EntityFrameworkCore with Identity Server4?

Tags: identityserver4

In which table access_token stored when we use EntityFrameworkCore with Identity Server4?

[image]
[image]

Comment: PersistedGrants sounds promising. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/ef.html#operational-store-support-for-authorization-grants-consents-and-tokens-refresh-and-reference

Comment: What makes you think they are stored in the database?

Comment: As described in this link(http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) two types of data moving to database. The first is the configuration data(resources, clients). The second is operational data(tokens, codes etc).

Comment: Did you read the documentation in the link I added in my earlier comment? Only refresh and reference tokens are saved.

Answer (score 0):

Access_Token are not directly stored in [PersistedGrants] table 
 
The key of this table is made up of access_token + ":" + grant which is then hashed using sha256
This makes it difficult to guess the access_token

Hope this helps.